# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException error on IE8

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have 2 .aspx pages. 1. Reporter.aspx 2. Report.aspx
Inside Reporter.aspx I have an IFRAME and Report.aspx is kept inside the IFRAME after submitting Report.aspx to server (to load report), I want to do another thing like showing some progress or something like that. My pages looks like the following

Reporter.aspx:
....................

```
<body style="margin:2px;">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">   
    <dx:ASPxPopupControl ClientInstanceName="LoadingPanel" ID="LoadingPanel" HeaderText="Progress" runat="server" ShowCloseButton="false" CloseAction="None"
        PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" EnableClientSideAPI="true" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" ShowShadow="true" Modal="true">
        <ContentCollection>
            <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl2" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" Height="75px" Width="275px" runat="server">
                    <center>
                        <div id="dvStatus" style="width:100%; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px; color:Red;" >Loading....</div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="../Content/images/loading_big.gif" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    </center>       
                </asp:Panel>
            </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
        </ContentCollection>                        
    </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
    </form>
    <div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">
        <iframe id="IFrame2" style="width:100%; border:0px; height:1125px; overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0" src="Report.aspx"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Report.aspx:
..................

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;">                   
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="7200">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="dvReportSettings" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 320px;" class="filterAndReport">                            
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>                                    
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>
            <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnGenerateReport" OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" Height="35px"
                            Width="100%" runat="server" Text="Generate" AutoPostBack="false">
                                <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){ValidatePage(s,e)}" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>                   
</body>
```

I have a button with ID="btnGenerateReport" and when I click it, it loads report. Some big reports take almost 2 hours to be generated and that is why I have 
set AsyncPostBackTimeout="7200" inside asp:ScriptManager. It works perfectly in different browsers like FireFox, Google Chrome, Safari but not in IE. When I 
click on Generate button using browser IE8, after few seconds it shows the following javascript error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 25 May 2011 10:47:06 UTC

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 12002
Line: 4723
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:64191/ScriptResource.axd?d=p4fjjEQSSdv063Ae96jd9UCqVNGWjRlsLyZLXU0H9gBYlcdCHSPhZBNLbZ-4XLN3zCzBInKdXuLlu4E1PtquQ3YdrPS-9wlk1EreB5wn-imBkTqz02jjBS_01qg6c4ObcqXGRK8Ejgyb3pvKkcBSH5V7xOadF8Jl4MSwWwtSDUBqxwNH0&t=fffffffff9d85fa6

Then I just put EnablePartialRendering="false" to asp:ScriptManager and tried to see if i can see some difference. After this, i click on Generate report button using
IE8 and found another javascript error after just few seconds like 10-15. Here is the error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; 
Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 25 May 2011 08:27:19 UTC

Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 264
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js

Is there anyone who can help me getting out from this IE error. I am in serious trouble.

Regrads,

Mohin

Comment: did u ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Status code 12002 suggests a script timeout. Although you have set the timeout high on the client (for asynchronous postbck), the server side has it's own ScriptTimeout setting in web.config or page directive.

Also I don't see why you need the nested update panel. From your decription of what you are doing one should be enough. Have the Generate Report button outside the update panel, and add a trigger element to the update panel for Generate Report button clicks.

Check your plugins in IE options, maybe disable all of them.

Comment: Well, I need nested update panels because inside the inner update panel i have report filter components that will be updated on dropdown_change event.
to set the time out in server side i have added
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="7200" maxRequestLength="4096" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
in web.config
it did not work
even I added AsyncTimeout="7200" in page directive of Report.aspx and it also did not work

Comment: I disabled all the ad ons from my IE and also ran IE in NO ad ons mode and no luck. Then I removes all the update panels and script manager from my page and tried to run a fresh page and found that after i click on Generate report button, the post back happens and after few seconds IE shows connection problem. Every time it shows the same error

Comment: Hi, is there any one who has solutions to this problem?

Comment: @Mohin The only other experience I have similar to your issue was with Anti-virus software, specifically AVG. When running projects on my dev box with IE8 and IIS 7.5 I would have all sorts of connectivity issues. As soon as I removed AVG all those issues disappeared. I swithced to Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Security Essentials, So it should not be any issue